# Getting NullPointerException after updating tagetSDK to 26

Tags: android

I have recently updated my targetSDK to 26 and getting random crashes in production, Not able to reproduce on my device and Logs also doesn't show any Activity/fragment where I Can check.
I am getting these crashes on **OS version 7.0, 8.0, 8.1**.
Here is the complete log crash from dev console:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState.getChild (DrawableContainer.java:916)
  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable (DrawableContainer.java:484)
  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange (StateListDrawable.java:110)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState (Drawable.java:775)
  at android.widget.CompoundButton.drawableStateChanged (CompoundButton.java:480)
  at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState (View.java:20421)
  at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:17640)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3421)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3421)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3421)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3421)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3421)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3421)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner (ViewGroup.java:5204)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout (ViewGroup.java:5140)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout (ViewGroup.java:5118)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView (ViewPager.java:1477)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4929)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:4902)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1434)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1759)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1827)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:797)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2596)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2383)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2338)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2215)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java:649)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate (FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1238)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1086)
  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java:1616)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22428)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1514)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:806)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:685)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22428)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6842)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22428)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1514)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:806)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:685)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22428)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6842)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22428)
```